# Rails joins(includes) belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a model User, which has many Photo.

I need to get users feed(photos from other users, users should be included), so query will be:

```
Photo.where(:user_id => Relationship.select(:followed_id).where(:follower_id => user.id)<<user.id).joins(:user)
```

But I get only photos, without user information. Is it possible to make query which returns something like this:

```
({user:{},photo:{}},{user:{},photo:{}},{user:{},photo:{}})
```

Comment: Might just be a matter of switching `joins` to `includes`. Out of curiousity, what's the query that it outputs? Have to admit I haven't tried passing another ARel query into the where method before.

Comment: It returns only photos. When i use includes, it makes 2 queries, one for photos and the second one - select from users. It looks also great, but it returns only photos too. It's look very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is important to understand here is that by using includes, rails directly returns the original model from the database (in this case Photo) but also loads into the memory all associated User models which may be queried via a photo. This approach assumes that DB query time is expensive and it is more efficient to spend memory space/CPU time.

Practically that means that after you perform your query:

```
@photos = Photo.where(:user_id => Relationship.select(:followed_id).where(:follower_id => user.id)<<user.id).includes(:user)
```

You can run:

```
@photos.first.user
```

This won't go to the DB for the user, but load it from the memory (which is considered cheap). So when you need a user of a photo all you need to do is run its `user` method, you don't have to pre-organize it in a `({user:{},photo:{}},{user:{},photo:{}},{user:{},photo:{}})` structure - just load the user when you need it.

If for some reason you have to organize it in this specific way you can:

```
@photos = Photo.where(:user_id => Relationship.select(:followed_id).where(:follower_id => user.id)<<user.id).includes(:user)

@photos = @photos.map {|p| {:user => p.user, :photo => p}
```

This will return an array containing photo and user hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you probably need one level of chained queries, as supposed to passing results in to another method as per your original post. This is completely untested, but i think it's in the direction of what you need to achieve. The idea is you get all relationship objects where the current user is the follower. Then you include user object, named follower. That symbol might need to be changed depending on how you defined the `belongs_to` in the relationship model. From there you include the photos.

Depending on the resulting query, it might throw errors. If it does, switch the symbols to strings, specifying the table names. Please edit your question with a stack trace if you do get an error trying this.

```
Relationship.where(:follower_id => user.id).includes(:follower).includes(:photos)
```